# CSC field disabled after setting up Paypal advanced with WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I have setup Paypal advanced with Woocommerce but while checking out the CSC field seems to be disabled thus the customer is unable to make a purchase , please let me know how to debug this.

Praveen

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a URL? Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 1):

I posted a help desk ticket with Woocommerce and they stated the settings are in your Paypal Manager account.

I then had to figure out how to adjust the settings, once you login to your Paypal Manager account you go to "Service Settings." You will then click "Set Up" where you will then navigate the the "Billing and Shipping Information" sections. Use the check boxes to select which fields are required and can be edited. Then click save

I had the same problem, checked the CSC check box and re-test and you should be good to go!